# iOS - best practice for managing code merge in a storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard, git-merge

Merging in a xcode storyboard with many team members can produce many conflicts etc.  I need a strategy to share a storyboard with 20 team members but to avoid the nightmares associated with merging code in a storyboard.

I thought of having a separate target per team in xcode but this doesn't do well as we all need the updates so having two story boards is not good practice.

my code base is inherited.  its a forked project that is storyboard heavy already. I think changing to xib might be difficult (??)

Comment: storyboard == nightmare for large team. there is no way around it. Some clients do it the very old fashioned way of XIBs and using code to push views. Otherwise I would recommend get one dedicated guy who will maintain the storyboard on his computer and do the merges manually.

Comment: we has same problem too. finally find the solution by adding viewcontrollers before edit/add their contents. then each one can work with own viewcontroller. this is also not a certain solution but less conflict then before (i think xcode handles region codes in storyboard xml)

Comment: Can you give a clear example. Are you saying I should in this order: 1. Create a VC 2. Change its class to my custom vc 3. Then change its content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404471/when-to-use-storyboard-and-when-to-use-xibs) tutorial which clearly suggests not using a `storyboard` while working on team.

But you can divide team into each module and use some versioning system as bitbucket or git to manage your code with the help of multiple storyboards(separate storyboard for separate module).

**Careful day by day commit and pull will definitely resolve conflicts.**

Comment: my code base is inherited.  its a forked project that is storyboard heavy already.

Comment: Yes you are right, It gives many conflicts during pull if working with team.

Comment: I did agree with your advices. While a team work on a large project. It's better to seperate UI into small XIB files. Each teamate could focus on their part. that could avoid some conflicts in a way.

Comment: @RyanChou Yes ,indeed..with multiple storyboard/xibs.

Answer (score 7):

Our team has found the majority of Michael Behan's method to work well. [⌘Boom](http://mbehan.com/post/77229582565/storyboards-multiple-developers-and-git)

- Everyone on the same build of Xcode
- Multiple storyboards
- Use Nibs for custom views
- Think about which storyboards are involved when assigning tasks
- Merge storyboards often