# iOS how to manage one storyboards for two or more developers

Tags: ios

Please help to solve my problem. we are two developer one working on same project but facing problem to edit same storyboard.

Comment: Take two different storyboards. Take module approach. For ex Registration Login Forgot Password etc should be done by 1st dev with a Registration Storyboard, And lets say Home page Side Panels etc should be done by other with other storyboard. Use Source Tree to manage conflicts

Comment: dont do it, avoid having 1 storyboard for the whole app, break your app up into more manageable pieces

Comment: As well as the above, use storyboard references too!

Comment: A tip: The suggestions given to you above, are quite right, but for some reason if you can not break storyboard into pieces, you can first merge the code files of the viewcontrollers then replace the whole controller from one storyboard to another, but still at this point two persons can not work on same viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better approach, use multiple storyboards as per the modules, it will decrease the chances of conflicts while merging the code, also there is a drawback using 1 storyboard i.e. if there will be a lot of controllers in your storyboard then it will take a lot of time to load.

Below are some reference links

[Link 1](http://mbehan.com/post/77229582565/storyboards-multiple-developers-and-git)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263725/ios-best-practice-for-managing-code-merge-in-a-storyboard)